# Discord bot not seeing guild members and new members joining

Tags: discord.py

I am having trouble getting my discord bot in python to see guild members (other than itself) or to trigger an action when a new member joins.

```
import os

import discord
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    for guild in client.guilds:
        print(
            f'{client.user} is connected to the following guild:\n'
            f'{guild.name}(id: {guild.id})'
        )
        for member in guild.members:
            print(
                f'{member.name}'
            )

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print(f'Someone has joined the server.')

client.run(TOKEN)
```

The bot has administrator privileges in the guild.
I have enabled all Privileged Intents on the bots page.

When run it can see that there are three members in the guild (guild.member_count) but only lists itself. It does absolutely nothing if a member leaves and rejoins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you are not passing intents to Client()

```py
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```